# How to kill a background worker in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I'm trying to kill a background worker in the `.DoWork` event of the worker.
I was using:

```
backgroundworker.CancelAsync()
```

But it shows an error saying `CancellationPending` does not allow

How can I kill a background worker after its work has completed its `.DoWork` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [WorkerSupportsCancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workersupportscancellation.aspx) property to `true` if you want to be able to send a cancellation request to the worker.